# High reliability, automatic reset, enable switch

Tags: switches, safety, reliability, industrial

I am currently facing the issue that I am currently working on a subsystem for a high power industrial automation system. The panel of this subsystem consists of a lot of components, however here only a 3-position turn switch as well as a safety switch are relevant.

The desired function is the following:
whenever the 3-state turn switch contacts to its center contact I would like to turn the safety switch back to its off position. This is so that whenever the operator switches the turn switch from position 1 to position 3 or vice-versa the safety switch is reset into its off position and needs to be manually enabled again.

My question is: How would one go about automatically disengaging a safety switch mechanically in a reliable way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what action disengages the safety switch now?

Comment: when the 3 position turn switch crosses it's middle contact it should turn off the safety switch

Comment: What you have described sounds to me like a 1-0-2 selection switch, where left or 1 position connects circuit 1, and the right or 2 position connects circuit 2. If you switch to the middle or 0 position, it's off or nothing is connected. It is used, for example, to switch between two power sources while not making any contact between them.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can I ask if this is a real equipment installation or theoretical design?

Comment: If you are working with components that already are selected or in place, please post links to their data so we can see what ewe have to work with.

Comment: @ EdinFifić well. basically i want the operator to require to operate another switch on top of that to specifically enable the rest of the circuitry. this second switch should turn to it's off position whenever the selection switch touches it's center contact so that the second switch needs to be operated again after turning the selector switch. @ jonathanjo thanks! this is a theoretical design only as of currently.

Comment: @ AnalogKid I do not have any of the two switches selected as of currently.

Comment: This is easy to do electrically.  No idea how to do it mechanically, especially not being able to see what you have available to you.

Comment: actually electrically works too as long as it is reliable because my test setup for an electrical version really didn't work out to be all that reliable. but yes you are probably right doing this mechanically is probably a bad idea, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electro-mechanical solution is the standard method of achieving this using standard components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXu51q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

How it works:

- A 3-position, centre-off, 2-pole switch is required along with a START (or RESET) button and a relay (SAFETY) capable of switching the load.
- When the switch is turned to POSN1 power is fed to the open START button.
- When START is pressed SAFETY relay is energised and power is fed to LAMP1. The SAFETY relay is latched on by its own contact.
- If the 3-position switch is switched back to centre position then both POSN1 contacts will open and SAFETY relay will drop out disabling the circuit.
- Switching to POSN2 works in a similar fashion.

Note that very fast switching between POSN1 and POSN2 could mean that the relay doesn't have time to drop out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xr3C.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A safer solution.*

Figure 2 ensures that the safety circuits drop out when switching from 1 to 2. START(b) is a second contact of the START button.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mechanical interlock mechanisms which might do what you want.

Here's a sketch of a 3-position rotary switch with a cam. When it is in position 2, the cam releases an e-stop switch of some kind.  (Spring-loaded MCB, for example, a conventional e-stop switch, or a microswitch, or many other possibilities.)

[image]